# React app / CSS : problem with transform and animation function

Tags: css, create-react-app

My problem is the following, I have an image centered on a web page, and I use the "transform" functions to allow to add images around this image having as reference the point in the center:

- My main image is at coordinate 0,0 (center of the page)
- My other images are at coordinates 0,0 (center) + transform: translateX (-150%) translateY (-120%)

This allows me when the page is "resized" to keep the same positions for each image.

Only I try to integrate a mini animation also circular:

```
  animation: flying 4s linear infinite;

  @keyframes flying {
    from {transform: rotate (0deg) translateX (2px) rotate (0deg); }
    to {transform: rotate (360deg) translateX (2px) rotate (-360deg); }
  }
```

The problem is that when I integrate this function, the first transform is ignored and the image is repositioned in the center...

Comment: Check in your browser's dev tools inspect facility. I think the CSS property transform in your animation will be flagged as having an invalid value - remove the spaces before the opening brackets.

Comment: Hi, the animation works, my image turns well, the problem is that the first transform which positions the image is "overwritten" by the second, which means that the image is no longer positioned in the right place but at the center of the page.

I would like to find a way to combine the 2